# Add Models/Entities/Objects to NgModule in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-modules

I've been trying to create an @NgModule (named **ModelsModule**) made of objects like User, Book, Library, Movie, and so on. Doing this I'm trying to not to import every object every time I need it but importing them at the beginning in the **AppModule** (main @NgModule) and use them as many times I want.

**Objects/Entities/Classes... example**

```
export class Author {
  constructor (
    public name: string,
    public avatar: string
  ) { }
}
```

**ModelsModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { Author } from './author/author.model';
(...)

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    Author,
    Book,
    Movie,
    Store
  ],
})
export class ModelsModule {}
```

**AppModule**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent, SettingsDialog } from './app.component';

// THAT ONE
import { ModelsModule } from '../models/models.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SettingsDialog
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    AppComponent,
    SettingsDialog
  ],
  providers: [
    // ModelsModule (?)
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    // ModelsModule (?)
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: That's a good practice, and actually how angular-cli constructs things. What is the problem/question?

Comment: You can't import simple classes to ngModule.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Model classes have no place in Angular. You just import the class into the file you need it, then use it.

```
import { MyModel } from './my.model';

class SomeComponent {
  model = new MyModel();
}
```

It seems a lot of newbies are confused about what the `import` statement are for in the class, and they think that they can somehow get rid of them by importing the class into Angular somehow. This is not the case. Importing the class into your file is nothing specific to Angular. File imports are simply a way for us to be able to use items from one file in another.