# Angular 2 Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for Member: (?).(…)

Tags: javascript, angular

I use [this seed application](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/) to narrow down an error that keeps popping up (so debugging is easier...)

I keep getting this error when trying to add a data model to my shared module (in my browser console):

```
Error: (SystemJS) Can't resolve all parameters for Member: (?).(…)
```

The `Member Class` in question:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Member {

  private id: string;
  [key: string]: any;

  constructor(private data?: any) {
    if (data) {
      this.id = data.id;
      _.extend(this, data.attributes);
    }
  }

}
```

My `SharedModule` (the `Member Class` isn't referenced anywhere else for now):

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ToolbarComponent } from './toolbar/index';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/index';
import { NameListService } from './name-list/index';

import { Member } from './models/member.model';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  declarations: [ToolbarComponent, NavbarComponent],
  exports: [ToolbarComponent, NavbarComponent,
    CommonModule, FormsModule, RouterModule]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [NameListService, Member]
    };
  }
}
```

When I get rid of the constructor in `class Member` the error disappears:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Member {

  private id: string;
  [key: string]: any;

}
```

I am not using barrel imports as you can see since the order of the imports can cause the same error.

I am a bit stuck on how to solve this... Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to inject into `Member`? Angular has no idea what you give you, as there's no token to go by. And are you sure you really want to make a _model_ a provider? What's the point?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40259357/2587435) and/or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40017679/2587435)

Comment: @peeskillet Sorry, I don't get your comment. 1) I am not trying to inject anything into `Member`. Member should just serve as a data model. I want to pass json attributes into the constructor. 2) How else can I use the class in a model? I need to provide it in order to have a new method, no?

Comment: Then why do you need to add it as a `provider`? Just import the file into your class, and `new` it. See my first link in the previous comment

Comment: Well if I don't and get rid of the `@Injectable` decorator, remove it from the providers and just import the class I get this error: `No provider for Member!`

Comment: Don't inject it. You don't inject model classes. You just import the class file, then just use it like a normal (non angular controlled class)

Comment: Damn, I finally got it. Trying to inject it was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class is just to be used as a model, then don't add it to the `@NgModule.providers` and don't try to inject it. Just import the class into the class file where you need it, and just use it like you would any other normal class

```
import { Member } from './member.model';

@Component({})
class MyComponent {
  member = new Member();
}
```

**See Also:**

- [Add Models/Entities/Objects to NgModule in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40260203/2587435)

Answer (score 2):

Classes with the `@Injectable()` decorator get instantiated once by Angular as service providers. Angular uses reflection/type hinting to supply the instance with its dependency's.

Angular doesn't know what to give your `Member` class's constructor since its type is defined as `any`.